# How to Print One Repeating Frame Record Per Page in Oracle Reports?

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I have a nested repeating frame as shown in the image. I want to print R_4 and R_5 repeating frame records as one record for each page. (One for R_4 and one for R_5). In an other saying I want to print R_1 repeating frame records as one record for each page. How can I set it?

I set R1, R4, and R5 properties like shown in the image. Now, just one page is showing. (Although there are 5 records) Why?

[image: R1]
[image: R4]
[image: R5]

Comment: Try to change the Vertical Elasticity - there might be not enough space to display more than one record. Also try changing "Print Object On" of the repeating frames to "First Page"...

Comment: "Print Object On" of the repeating frames to "First Page" is work but why? 
Does not have to be "All Pages"? Because it prints to all pages.

Comment: "Print Object On" for repeating frames means that the hole content of it should be printed on every page. But what you want is to print the data only once, so you have to use "First Page", which starts on the first page and then prints the data only once...

Comment: So, how about "All Pages"?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, horizontal elasticity should be "Fixed", but - vertical elasticity should be "Variable".

As of R_4 and R_5: set their properties as

- page protect: yes (so that all their objects are kept on the same page, if possible)
- page break before: yes (so that every frame prints on its own page).

  - possibly, leave R_4's property as "no", but R_5's as "yes"